# VS 2008 keeps removing and re-adding <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2015

I've got a VS 2008 C# Web project and whenever I make some changes to the files in it (not even to the project file itself) VS will remove some lines like this from the csproj file:

```
<SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
```

So something like this:

```
<Compile Include="Default.aspx.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Default.aspx</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
</Compile>
```

will become

```
<Compile Include="Default.aspx.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Default.aspx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

**BUT** the next time I work on this project it will add those lines back! It keeps going back and forth like this, resulting in a lot of meaningless "changes" in our source control system. This never used to happen with VS 2005 and it doesn't seem to be happening for other developers who work on the same project file, only for me.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can stop it from doing this?

Comment: how strange, this has just happened to me for the first time. I checked in my solution last night and this morning my .csproj file has changed. having had a little dig around on Google it seems that this has affected a handful of people for years! but no reason or resolution so far as I can see..

Comment: same here, this is currently happening to me

Comment: I have the same problem except the the subtype element does not added again. Only happens to me as well and not to any of the other developers on the team. I have a discussion about it [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/aadf38d2-3987-4d9d-80f8-6dc99bb5e0f0), hopefully I will get some answers.

Comment: Happening to me as well. Totally obnoxious. Two people on the team have VS that do this while the others don't. Seems like something in a hotfix is doing this. No help out there for this that I can find.

Comment: this is currently happening to me, but me I have Visual studio 2010

Comment: Happening on Visual Studio 2015 as well.

Comment: Happening in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 as well :(

Comment: @PitzZh's answer is probably going to be deleted. Reproducing here: *"Please vote for this bug in Microsoft Bug Report System for VS2017. [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/389773/vs-2017-keeps-removing-and-re-adding-aspxcodebehin.html](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/389773/vs-2017-keeps-removing-and-re-adding-aspxcodebehin.html)"*.

Answer (score 11):

For me, the difference depends on whether or not the web project is open in Visual Studio.

I find if I commit the project file to version control with the project open in Visual Studio the SubType elements are present. Closing the solution/project then removes the SubType elements from the project file. Now I always ensure my commits are performed with the project closed in VS to avoid unnecessary changes to the project file.

Answer (score 6):

Working on VS2010 and solved this issue by deleting solutionFileName.sln.DotSettings.user file and solutionFileName.suo. That helped me, give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

Splitting the content of your file into multiple files - one file per class may help.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=283434

Up-to-date link:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/389773/vs-2017-keeps-removing-and-re-adding-aspxcodebehin.html

Comment: Thanks, but no, that doesn't help - I only have the one class (an ASPX page codebehind class) in each affected file.

Comment: I had the same problem with VS 2015: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1650262
It happens for code-behind files with multiple classes. Reordering classes fixes the problem (main page / control class should be first in code behind file)

Answer (score 0):

These lines are also appearing in the project file in VS2012 when committing project changes in Tortoise SVN. This project used to be a website that I converted into a web application.

I was able to bypass this issue using the following steps which **do not** require closing the project:

1. Just prior to committing to SVN, clean the solution using "BUILD > Clean Solution".
2. Click the "Save All" button to save the project file.
3. Commit changes using Tortoise SVN.
4. Continue working on project...